# What would you send in 10 m³ to the medieval age, and how would you obtain it?

Tags: economy, time-travel, social-norms

So my protagonist has received "future data" because of this he is sure that a space that is 10 meters cubed will be transported back in time to a medieval time and place outlined in the data. "future data" gives my protagonist one year to prepare and 200,000$ in cash.

I figure my protagonist. A modern college aged male with some education would take the time google a response.

I plan to hand wave language and future diseases.

Rules:

1. The protagonist can not change the date or space that he is being moved to or from.
2. The protagonist must plan to be in the space at the end of the year.
3. The physical rules of the world still apply.
4. Anything can be inside the space.
5. Assume a semi hostile environment where he lands maybe being labelled a heretic.
6. Assume a departure date some where around 2019 if it makes a difference.

The question:

Part 1. How can you get the most resources in a one year period with starting cash of 200,000$? Inside the USA. You can do illegal things but need to reasonable be able to avoid being under arrest in 1 year.

Part 2. What items would be necessary for long term survival in a medieval European space, and most important for simple quality of life. (good shoes, quality axes)

Part 3. assuming you have a 10 * 10 * 10 space what would be most beneficial to you to bring with you in order to become either the most powerful/richest person on the planet by the time you die?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Welcome to the site, ChaosCenturian. If you would please [edit] your post to include the specific question you want/need the community's help with, we would be more than happy to provide a solution(s) to your problem. As it is, it's hard to tell what, exactly, you're asking and this question is likely to be put on hold until you provide sufficient clarification.

Comment: Hello and welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! Currently there is no question here. Please edit your your text so that there is a question. You might also want to take the [tour](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help). Have fun!

Comment: The edit helps, but I think you should explain your goal. If I just want to survive I might pack different things than if I plan to conquer the world. Generally asking what we would do is opinion-based, meaning there is no objective way to rate answers.

Comment: I tried to give this question a more descriptive title. That said, unfortunately I think this is a textbook example of a *primarily opinion-based* question, as there is no way to judge objectively how well any given answer actually answers the question. Such questions are just a poor fit for our format. ChaosCenturian, I recommend that you review https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/asking, particularly https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask and https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Spices are a commodity that's worth little in the present, and a lot in the past. Just sayin'.

Comment: Medieval when and where? Some idea of a target date will help. Technology varied enormously across the world in this era. What might be useful in one place not so much in another.